# cython_bbox.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, cntk

I try to do all these steps because I want a different version python 3.5 on linux to run the code in this example  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Object-Detection-using-Fast-R-CNN

If you need a different version you can compile it following these steps:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn.git
cd $FRCN_ROOT/lib
make
python setup.py build_ext --inplace.
copy the generated cython_bbox and cython_nms binaries from 
$FRCN_ROOT/lib/utils to $CNTK_ROOT/Examples/Image/Detection/FastRCNN/fastRCNN/utils
**Error**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C1_DrawBboxesOnImages.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cntk_helpers import *
  File "/home/tftuts/Desktop/tensorflow/CNTK-master/Examples/Image/Detection/FastRCNN/cntk_helpers.py", line 13, in <module>
    from fastRCNN.nms import nms as nmsPython
  File "/home/tftuts/Desktop/tensorflow/CNTK-master/Examples/Image/Detection/FastRCNN/fastRCNN/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .imdb import imdb
  File "/home/tftuts/Desktop/tensorflow/CNTK-master/Examples/Image/Detection/FastRCNN/fastRCNN/imdb.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .utils.cython_bbox import bbox_overlaps
ImportError: /home/tftuts/Desktop/tensorflow/CNTK-master/Examples/Image/Detection/FastRCNN/fastRCNN/utils/cython_bbox.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

please any one can help me. what means

```
cython_bbox.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

and how resolve this problem.

Answer (score 11):

This error message is typical when there's a version mismatch in Python modules. It could something like `cython_bbox.so` was compiled and linked against Python 2.7 and CNTK was compiled against Python 3.5. It's hard to say exactly what the reason is but you can try to do `make` inside a python environment that matches your CNTK version and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out my `/usr/bin/python` symbolic link was pointing to `/usr/bin/python2` instead of `/usr/bin/python3`. Changing it to point to `/usr/bin/python3` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

try compile it with python3.

The default python version in Linux maybe 2.x

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the python version mismatch. As default, it is compiled with python 2.7.

Edit the make.sh file to compile with python3 and compile once again.

For instance,

change `python setup.py` to `python3 setup.py`

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: where is the file please make.sh